# Report Server as Azure Managed SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, azure, reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I am a beginner in Azure.I have a query, appreciate if someone can help me. My Team is planning to Install SSRS on VM, But report server as Azure Managed SQL database. We already have sql database on premise. So there will be three layers:

1. Database on premise
2. Report Server on Azure Managed SQL Server instance
3. VM machine which will be running SSRS

Will this work?

Answer (score 0):

You can't install SSRS side-by-side on Azure SQL Database Managed Instance. As you mentioned in 3. you've have to run SSRS on a VM or switch to [Power BI](https://powerbi.microsoft.com).
See Video [Modernize your on-premises applications with SQL Database Managed Instances](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-f_9gScnEB4) starting at 24:12.
For connecting a Managed Instance to linked server or another on-premises data store see [Configure a VNet for Azure SQL Database Managed Instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-managed-instance-vnet-configuration)